# Doubt about SVD algorithm

Tags: matlab, svd, time-series

I am studing the SSA (Singular Spectrum Analysis) algorithm and after reading some papers about SSA, the ideia was not consolidated.
I found a Matlab SSA algorithm [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8115-singular-spectrum-analysis-smoother/content/ssa.m) and I was trying to implement my own SSA, just to get more understanding about it. 
My question is just about the SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) step. I would like to know how to substitute the SVD from this code to the `svd()` implemented by `Matlab`. I did a comparison of results between the `svd()` by `Matlab` and the SVD implemented by [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8115-singular-spectrum-analysis-smoother/content/ssa.m) code and the only difference is the part `V=(X')*U;` that `V` is different from the `V` from `svd()` of `Matlab`. Why this two SVD are differents ? How can I just use the `svd()` implemented by `Matlab` to implement the SSA ?

note: I have an SVD algorithm implemented in other language than Matlab and I want to implement SSA reusing this SVD code.

note 2: X is a time series and the SVD is performed on XX'.

Comment: My advice is that you should use the Matlab SVD. The formation of products like $A^A$ or $AA^t$ reduces the accuracy of the computed SVD. A considerable amount of research went into the development of SVD algorithms to avoid such nasty matrix multiplications.